# Combining multiple records into one based on some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have this following table:

```
payee      |  payer    |  amount
-----------|-----------|----------
USER3      |  USER1    |  150.00
USER3      |  USER2    |  50.00
USER1      |  USER3    |  300.00
USER2      |  USER3    |  300.00
USER3      |  USER6    |  100.00
```

I want to combine two records where payee is payer of second record and payer is the payee of second record and recalculate the amount. 
So my required result is:

```
payee      |  payer      |  amount
---------- | ------------| ---------
USER1      |  USER3      |  150.00
USER2      |  USER3      |  250.00
USER3      |  USER6      |  100.00
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases have `least()` and `greatest()` functions, so one way is:

```
select least(payee, payer) as payee, greatest(payee, payer) as payer,
       sum(case when payee = least(payee, payer) then amount else - amount end) as amount
from t
group by least(payee, payer), greatest(payee, payer);
```

(In those that don't you can use a `case` expression.)

If you always want positive numbers, you can use a subquery:

```
select (case when amount < 0 then payer else payee end) as payee,
       (case when amount < 0 then payee else payer end) as payer,
       abs(amount)
from (select least(payee, payer) as payee, greatest(payee, payer) as payer,
             sum(case when payee = least(payee, payer) then amount else - amount end) as amount
      from t
      group by least(payee, payer), greatest(payee, payer)
     ) t;
```

Comment: for least and greatest I created user defined function. It worked perfectly.